# parsec parser for c++ functions?

Tags: c++, parsing, haskell, clang, parsec

is there any open source parser implementation for c++ functions with parsec?

can't find any, dont want to use libClang, becuase installation failes

Comment: depending on what info you want, gccxml / pygccxml might give you signatures. It's bound to be a lot of work, but at least it parses all C++ that g++ accepts, which can be important. (C++ is a rather unruly langauge). gccxml is slow though.

Comment: Are you looking for a C++ parser usable from within Haskell or a C++ parser usable from within C++?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the speed of GCCXML, but to a functional programmer used to algebraic data types its AST is mighty unpleasant. As for the question, I know Stack Overflow discourages this sort of opinion but using Haskell is a non-starter, its not that Haskell wouldn't be suitable just that there's so much groundwork to do. If you must parse C++ choose a system where the parser exists, so that's the commercial DMS system of Semantic Designs or the EDG parser (used by Coverity for instance). Maybe ANTLR now has a workable parser, I suspect it's the only candidate in the Open Source world.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Why? C++ is very, very difficult to parse. So while there are pure Haskell parsers for C (e.g [Language.C](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/language-c)) there is *no C++ parser implemented yet*, other than the libclang binding which you are already aware of.

---

*References*:

- [haskell/libclang](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/LibClang), a C++ parser using clang
- [haskell/language-c](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/language-c), a C parser in pure Haskell.

Comment: Note that this isn't a problem with Parsec; it's the result of the brain-damaged syntax of C++.

Comment: @John L - Glass houses? Stones? The only thing that can parse current day (Glasgow) Haskell is GHC, even H98 can't be parsed without a special normalization phase between the lexer and parser to handle layout. While I like the power of all the GHC extensions, its not unreasonable to consider Glasgow Haskell the C++ of functional languages...

Comment: @stephen tetley: haskell-src-exts claims to be able to parse all GHC extensions.  I admit the layout rule makes parsing harder, however there's a world of difference between the complexity of H98 and C++.  Also note that parsing is still one of the weakest parts of C++ despite having orders of magnitude more work put into dev. tools.

Comment: @John L - true, I remembered about Haskell-Src-Exts after posting. I think my point still stands though. If you look at Hare or Programmatica, Haskell "meta tools" inevitably fall by the wayside. Only HPC seems to keep up because it is part of GHC.